# How to pass array of images over to another view?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uiimageview

I have a CollectionView with about 12 images. When I tap on an image it should display that image blown up on the next screen. The problem is that after that specific image I tap shows up it has to animate through the rest of the 11 images. How would I go about doing that? I have the code that animates through an array of images I just don't know how to show a specific image that I tap on then start animating through the array.

Here is my sample code!

```
func convertUrlsToImage() {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
        for urls in self.arrayOfImageUrlsFromOtherView {
            if let url = NSURL(string: urls) {
                if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
                    if let hingeImage = UIImage(data: data) {
                        self.convertedURLToImages.append(hingeImage)

                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { 
                            if self.galleryImageView.image == nil {
                                self.galleryImageView.image = self.convertedURLToImages[0]
                            }else{
                                print("Not empty")
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
}

func animateThroughArrayOfImages() {
    let currentIndex =  convertedURLToImages.indexOf(galleryImageView.image!)
    let nextIndex  = (currentIndex! + 1) % self.convertedURLToImages.count

    self.title = "\(nextIndex+1)"  + "/\(convertedURLToImages.count)"
    self.galleryImageView.image  = self.convertedURLToImages[nextIndex]
}
```

//Additional Code

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) {

        performSegueWithIdentifier("nextView", sender: cell)

    }else{
        print("no good")
    }
}







override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {





    if let indexPath = self.collectionView?.indexPathForCell(sender as! ImageCollectionViewCell) {

        if segue.identifier == "nextView" {

            let galleryViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! GalleryViewController


           //We are passing the url to the next screen then making another request to show them
           let imageUrl = hingeImagesArray[indexPath.row]


            //passesd a single image url
            galleryViewController.imageUrlFromOtherScreen = imageUrl.imageUrl






            //Pasing array of urls 
            galleryViewController.arrayOfImageUrlsFromOtherView = hingeImageUrls

            //let myIndex = testImageArray[indexPath.row]








        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your task looks pretty simple. Just implement this delegate for collectionView

```
optional func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

Then get your image index from *indexPath*. Then you can pass this index with urls array to the your next screen and use it to set initial image.

But anyway it's not a great idea to store all images in one in-memory array.

Comment: Thats for the help but I think I did that bus am still confused. Please look at the additional code I added and let me know what modifications I should make! I need to set the initial image based on the collectionView cell someone tapped and then cycle through the rest of the array. My code always sets it to the the first cell images in the array self.galleryImageView.image = self.convertedURLToImages[0] . I don't know how to make it the picture the user tapped instead of this static index!

Comment: Why not give your `galleryViewController` a `selectedIndex` property that you can set in `prepareForSegue` and then use that as the starting point for the animation.  Your last comment in the additional code almost seems to be doing that.

Comment: @sgib Can you show me an example(code) please? I never have done that before. Thanks

Comment: In prepareForSegue add a line `galleryViewController.selectedIndex = indexPath.row` then in your galleryViewController instead of saying `self.galleryImageView.image = self.convertedURLToImages[0]` simply use the index there; `galleryImageView.image = convertedURLToImages[selectedIndex]` and of course you will need to define the `selectedIndex` Int property in galleryViewController.